# Generating small world network with fixed degree

Tags: r

I would like to generate a small world network with a fixed degree of 10.

I have tried watts.strogatz.game(1, 100, 5, 0) which results in a degree of 10 but only 5 neighbours for each node.

I'm guessing this is because the network is undirected. is there any way to make it undirected?

Comment: 1 question is what is the appropriate way of obtaining any network in the above format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `igraph` package contains many functions to create and manipulate graphs.
In particular, the `get.edgelist` function returns the list of edges, in the format you want.

The `erdos.renyi.game` function, when you set the probability to 1, generates complete graphs.

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(5, 1)
plot(g1)
get.edgelist(g1)
```

The `degree.sequence.game` function generates random graphs with a prescribed degree distribution.

```
g2 <- degree.sequence.game( c(3,3,3,2,1,1,1), method="vl" )
plot(g2)
```

The `watts.strogatz.game` function generates small-world networks.

```
g <- watts.strogatz.game(1, 100, 5, 0.05)
plot(g)
```

Comment: In the small-world case the degree is not fixed. If you really want to fix the degrees, then first generate the lattice with rewiring probability set to zero, and then call the `rewire()` function, which rewires edges while keeping the degrees fixed.

Comment: you mean by using graph.lattice(100,0,nei=5,directed=TRUE) ? when I look at degree() there are some nodes that have degree below 10. is there any way to have the same degree of 10 for each node in the lattice?

Comment: also using rewire() how can I specify the rewiring probability?

Comment: You want a circular lattice, e.g., `graph.lattice(100,0,nei=5,circular=TRUE)`
or `watts.strogatz.game(1, 100, 5, 0)`, otherwise the nodes on the edges have fewer neighbours.
The argument of `rewire` is the number of rewirings, rather than a probability.

Comment: but if I use either of these commands, some nodes will still have fewer contacts. e.g. in your code node 97 has only 2 contacts while others have 4. why is that?

Comment: The code in the answer (the [Watts and Strogatz model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model))
does not keep the degrees constant. 
The code in the comments does: 
`degree( rewire(watts.strogatz.game(1, 100, 5, 0), niter=100) )`
confirms that all nodes have degree 10.

Comment: in this case I'm using niter 100 which corresponds to a probability of 1 of rewiring? would niter 50 be 0.5?

Comment: The notion of "probability of rewiring" may be difficult to define in this case.
For the Watts-Strogatz model, we just select a proportion p of the edges and rewire them.
But the `rewire` function _iteratively_ selects pairs of edges and exchanges their endpoints:
the same edge can be selected several times.
If the number of iterations is sufficiently small for the probability that an edge is selected twice to be negligible,
the number of edges rewired is `2*niter`
and the proportion of rewired edges is `2*niter/number_of_edges`
(there are 500 edges in the graph in my previous comment).

Comment: so if I want to rewire with probability 0.1 then I should set niter to 25? 2*25/500=0.1?

Comment: Approximately, yes. Since some edges will be rewired several times, slightly less than 10% of the edges will be displaced, but the error is small, and will be even smaller if you consider larger graphs.