# Generate fixed degree small world network

Tags: r, social-networking

I would like to create diffetent variants of the small-world network (Watts and Strogatz) by varying the re-wiring probability, but instead of having a mean degree, I would like to have a fixed degree.

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried

```
watts.strogatz.game(1, 100, 10, 0.1)
```

this should give a degree of 10. but if I don't want multiple edges and loops then after

```
simplify(graph)
```

I get edges with degree less than 10.

Comment: I have tried watts.strogatz.game(1, 100, 10, 0.1) this should give a degree of 10. but if I don't want multiple edges and loops then after simplify(graph) I get edges with degree less than 10.

Comment: A [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355289/generating-social-networks-with-different-properties-in-r/14357187#comment19969273_14357187) to one of your previous question suggested to use `wire` directly to preserve the degree.